# Script does not exist at specified location || CodeDeploy issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, cloud, aws-code-deploy

I'm executing sample powershell scripts as part of deployment via CodeDeploy. Below is content of appsec.yml

```
version: 0.0
os: windows
files:
  - source: \
    destination: C:\Users\Administrator\testapp
hooks:
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: C:\Users\Administrator\testapp\stop.ps1
      timeout: 300

  BeforeInstall:
    - location: C:\Users\Administrator\testapp\copy.ps1
      timeout: 300

  ApplicationStart:
    - location: C:\Users\Administrator\testapp\start.ps1
      timeout: 300

  ValidateService:
    - location: C:\Users\Administrator\testapp\validate.ps1
      timeout: 300
```

But when I'm starting deployment with code deploy, getting below error:

```
Error code
ScriptMissing
Script name
C:\Users\Administrator\testapp\copy.ps1
Message
Script does not exist at specified location: C:/ProgramData/Amazon/CodeDeploy/85c23e0a-90f5-474e-9675-df3301a3b8f9/d-CODHEXCG5/deployment-archive/C:/Users/Administrator/testapp/copy.ps1
```

When I checked location C:/ProgramData/Amazon/CodeDeploy/85c23e0a-90f5-474e-9675-df3301a3b8f9/d-CODHEXCG5/deployment-archive, I see artifacts are downloaded from S3 buckets.

Artifacts directory structure:

```
+ deployment-archive
  + scripts
     - copy.ps1
     - stop.ps1
     - start.ps1
     - validate.ps1
  - appsec.yml
```

I think files are not getting copied from Deployment Archive to destination I mentioned in appsec file. But why its not getting copied, not able to understand.
Please guide

Comment: Arent you forgetting about `scripts`, i.e., C:\Users\Administrator\testapp\scripts\stop.ps1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `files` section is totally correct (see [AppSpec 'files' section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-files.html)), and the problem is the scripts in `hooks` section.

In this official documentation [AppSpec 'hooks' section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html#appspec-hooks-server), it said:

> The location of scripts you specify in the 'hooks' section is relative to the root of the application revision bundle.

So, you need to change the absolute path to a relative path, like:

```yaml
hooks:
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: scripts\stop.ps1
      timeout: 300
```

And your error log also tells you the same issue:

> Script does not exist at specified location: C:/ProgramData/Amazon/CodeDeploy/85c23e0a-90f5-474e-9675-df3301a3b8f9/d-CODHEXCG5/deployment-archive/C:/Users/Administrator/testapp/copy.ps1

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I modified hook section as you suggested and it worked